# Convert input to int regardless user input

Tags: c

I have the following c code and want to make sure that even though the user enters a float, this will be converted to int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int i, times, total;
  float average = 0.0;
  int * pArr;

  printf("For how many numbers do you want the average calculated?\n");

  scanf("%d", &times);

  pArr = (int *) malloc(times * sizeof(int));

  printf("Please enter them down here\n");

  for(i=0;i<times;i++) {
    scanf("%d", &pArr[i]);
    total += pArr[i];
  }

  average = (float) total / (float) times;
  printf("The average of your numbers is %.2f\n", average);

  return 0;
}
```

So the problem here now is that when the user enters a float, the program terminates. Any clue?

Comment: don't use `scanf` then. tokenize and convert to integer using `strtol` so it will stop at the dot if there is one

Comment: Use `scanf("%f", &temp)` where `temp` is a float. When you store it in the array, `pArr[i] = temp` the value will be converted to an `int`.

Comment: `%d` format causes `scanf()` to stop when it encounters a `'.'`.   That dot is left in the input buffer.   The next call of `scanf()` with `%d` format encounters it immediately, and returns without reading any further.   In your code, if input is `2.3`, the value of `times` will be read as `2`, and all the other calls of `scanf()` will return without reading anything.

Comment: simple but that may lead to possible rounding errors

Comment: Do you want to float given by the user to be rounded?

Comment: Well I understand the drawbacks of `scanf` but I don't want to use `round()` or `floor` or `ceil` and so on. Hmm

Comment: If you don't want to use `round` or `floor` or `ceil`, what behavior _do_ you want if the user enters `2.3`? The only options really are those (plus some minor variations on `round` and `floor`), or leaving the `.3` in the buffer (which you obviously don't want, because it breaks the rest of your code).

Comment: Also, what should happen if the user enters, say, `4e2`? Do you want to treat that as `4` and leave an `e2` in the buffer to fail later, or treat it as the integer 400, or something else?

Comment: @abarnert, well maybe I need to `floor` but I don't know. My logic is not helping me at the moment

Comment: @holasz isn't `floor` just the same as ignoring everything past the `.`?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic yeah. 2.2 becomes 2 and 3.5 becomes 3 and so on.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic "... floor just the same as ignoring everything past the ."  No:  `floor(-3.6) != -3`.

Comment: @chux Good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` will stop scanning when it encounters a dot. So direct scanning of input isn't possible.

But you can workaround it by scanning a *string*, then scanning the integer from your string. That's poor error checking but at least it drops the float part and you can enter floats or integers (also note that `total` wasn't initialized, and `gcc -Wall -Wextra` doesn't even detect that).

Find a working version below (would need more error checking when entering integers though):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int i, times, total = 0;  // don't forget to initialize total to 0 !!!
  float average = 0.0;
  int * pArr;
  char temp[30];
  printf("For how many numbers do you want the average calculated?\n");

  scanf("%d", &times);

  pArr = malloc(times * sizeof(int)); // don't cast the return value of malloc

  printf("Please enter them down here\n");

  for(i=0;i<times;i++) {
    scanf("%29s",temp);   // scan in a string first
    sscanf(temp,"%d", &pArr[i]);  // now scan the string for integer
    total += pArr[i];
  }

  average = (float) total / (float) times;
  printf("The average of your numbers is %.2f\n", average);

  free(pArr);  // it's better to free your memory when array isn't used anymore
  return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- the array allocation & storage isn't useful here if you only compute the average of the values)
- you're not protected against a valid floating point exponent input: if `1e10` is entered, the value `1` is scanned (as opposed to `"%f"` method of the other answer that would work, but that I fear has a risk rounding error)

Comment: `scanf("%29s",temp);` is more adequate.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Although, one thing remaining. When entering e.g `2.2` it will accept only 1 time to enter a digit. Not what this is caused by?

Comment: @snr I want the average to be in float but not when asking me how many times I have to enter a number before the average shows up.

Comment: Thanks!  I will figure the last part out. It works as expected!

Comment: What are the advantages of this approach over scanning a float and casting to an int?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the user input to be rounded to the nearest int you can simply read it in as a float and then cast to an int.

```
float in = 0.0f;
scanf("%f", &in);   // Read as float
pArr[i] = (int) in; // Cast to int
```

Comment: Try reading in "2000000001" and then see what `pArr[i]` holds.

Comment: @chux Neither my solution or this solution is perfect. It depends on the context. This solution is better if the user enters 1e4 for instance, but yes, you want to avoid those rounding errors

Comment: `float` in C is seldom a good choice unless there are memory size  or embedded concerns.  So much of C's  code promotes to `double`  math given FP constants are `double` by default. OP's final `printf("...  %.2f\n", average)` can invoke `double` math as `average` can be expected to convert to `double` and `printf()` then itself may do a lot of `double` math.  Using a FP type to save scanned  input to cope with OP's `"."` is a reasonable idea, yet the little `float`   unnecessary constrains precision.  Better to use  `double` for this approach.